# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE avoiding duplicates

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I'm using this LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement to quickly upload files.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file_location/file.txt'
    INTO TABLE mytable 
    FIELDS TERMINATED by '\t'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 18 LINES //ignore some header info
    (sampleID, testID);
```

But there are some files that I've already loaded in the past and I want to avoid duplications.

The database structure includes an auto incrementing PK as an additional column.

Without having to open each file and do a search prior to uploading in order to determine whether those records are already there, is there a way of modifying the command I am using to ignore duplicate rows based on having both sampleID and testID rows in table being matched to the incoming file?

For example, supposing the current table has the following rows:

```
tablePKID    sampleID    testID
    0         0001        A
    1         0001        B
    2         0003        A
    3         0003        B
```

And I wish to import a file with the following records

```
  0001        A
  0001        B
  0001        C
  0005        A
  0005        B
```

How can I ensure only

```
  0001        C
  0005        A
  0005        B
```

are imported?

Comment: Any keys on the table?

Comment: 'If you specify IGNORE, rows that duplicate an existing row on a unique key value are discarded' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: column "tablePKID" is an auto-increment PK - i would like to specify what constitutes a duplicate event, ie in my case rows with columns sampleID and testID both matching with incoming row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you got tablePKID to auto increment from 0 putting that to one side for now you can specify a unique key on samplid and testid and load..IGNORE for example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T
(tablePKID   INT auto_increment primary key, 
sampleID VARCHAR(10),   testID VARCHAR(10));

alter table t
    add unique key k1(sampleid,testid);

INSERT INTO T (sampleid,testid) VALUES
(   '0001'   ,     'A'),
(   '0001'   ,     'B'),
(   '0003'   ,     'A'),
(   '0003'   ,     'B');
```

File data.txt

```
sampleid    testid
"0001"  "A"
"0001"  "B"
"0001"  "C"
"0005"  "A"
"0005"  "B"


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.1\\data\\sandbox\\data.txt'
     ignore
    INTO TABLE t 
    FIELDS TERMINATED by '\t'
    enclosed by '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES 
    (sampleID, testID);

+-----------+----------+--------+
| tablePKID | sampleID | testID |
+-----------+----------+--------+
|         1 | 0001     | A      |
|         2 | 0001     | B      |
|         3 | 0003     | A      |
|         4 | 0003     | B      |
|         5 | 0001     | C      |
|         6 | 0005     | A      |
|         7 | 0005     | B      |
+-----------+----------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: tablePKID to auto increment from 0 was a manual entry. thanks for pointing it out and thanks for solution

Comment: I should point out that in order for the the unique keys to be added to a populated table that the existing duplicates must be removed first, otherwise a 1062 error is encountered